# In the grammar structure 又 [adjective] 又 [adjective], is there anything wrong with combining a negative adjective with a positive one?

Tags: grammar

**Question**: In the grammar structure 又 [adjective] 又 [adjective], is there anything wrong with combining a negative adjective with a positive one?

It seems like it would make a confusing sentence to mix both positivity and negativity.  Such sentences might be better off being written using the grammar structure 虽然 ... 但是 ...  But perhaps they're perfectly okay.

Some examples I made up:

> 我的女儿又[漂亮](http://dict.cn/%E6%BC%82%E4%BA%AE)又[淘气](http://dict.cn/%E6%B7%98%E6%B0%94)
> My daugther is both beautiful and naughty
> <sub>Wǒ de nǚ'ér yòu piàoliang yòu táoqì</sub>
>
> 这辆车又[快](http://dict.cn/%E5%BF%AB)又[旧](http://dict.cn/%E6%97%A7)
> This car is both fast and old
> <sub>Zhè liàng chē yòu kuài yòu jiù</sub>
>
> 我的作业又[难](http://dict.cn/%E9%9A%BE)又[有兴趣](http://dict.cn/%E6%9C%89%E5%85%B4%E8%B6%A3)
> My homework is both difficult and interesting
> <sub>Wǒ de zuòyè yòu nán yòu yǒuxìngqù</sub>

The examples I've read never seem to mix negative adjectives with positive ones.  Some examples I "borrowed" from jukuu.com:

> 他有点成问题，又[懒](http://dict.cn/%E6%87%92)、又[邋遢](http://dict.cn/%E9%82%8B%E9%81%A2)、又[不讲卫生](http://dict.cn/%E4%B8%8D%E8%AE%B2%E5%8D%AB%E7%94%9F)
> <sub>Tā yǒudiǎn chéng wèntí, yòu lǎn, yòu lātà, yòu bù jiǎng wèishēng</sub>
>
> 他又[高](http://dict.cn/%E9%AB%98)又[瘦](http://dict.cn/%E7%98%A6)，穿得很差
> <sub>Tā yòu gāo yòu shòu, chuān dé hěn chà.</sub>
>
> 这就是为什么糖块是又[快](http://dict.cn/%E5%BF%AB)又[好](http://dict.cn/%E5%A5%BD)的能量来源
> <sub>Zhè jiùshì wèishéme táng kuài shì yòu kuài yòu hǎo de néngliàng láiyuán</sub>
>
> 她听说白兰德家族又[有钱](http://dict.cn/%E6%9C%89%E9%92%B1)又有[地位](http://dict.cn/%E5%9C%B0%E4%BD%8D)
> <sub>Tā tīngshuō báilándé jiāzú yòu yǒuqián yòu yǒudìwèi</sub>

Comment: Yes they look weird. The adjs should be relevant at least.

Comment: **既...又...** or **又...又...** or **不仅/不但...而且...** means **not only ... but also ...**, **既...又...还/也** or **又...又...又...** or **不仅/不但...而且...还**, I don't how to express in English.

Comment: 1. 他很不爱干净，又懒惰又邋遢，又不讲卫生。2. 他很不爱干净，既懒惰又邋遢，还不讲卫生。3. 他很不爱干净，不仅懒惰，而且邋遢，还不讲卫生。

Comment: You may speak 我的女儿虽然漂亮但很淘气, 这辆车虽然旧但是很快, 作业虽然难但我很有兴趣.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: In the grammar structure 又 [adjective] 又 [adjective], is there anything wrong with combining a negative adjective with a positive one

Yes, there's something wrong with combining a negative adjective with a positive one in the [又 [adjective A] 又 [adjective B] structure.

The problem is -- You can't do that!

All the examples you made up are wrong. [又(A) 又 (B)] is equal to [(A) and (B)] in English.

> (A) and (B) have to be both positive or both negative

Example:

(both positive)

[又(迅速)又(准确)] = [(fast) and (accurate)]

We don't say  "his punch is fast but accurate" in English ; We only say "his punch is fast and accurate"

~

(both negative)

[又(贪心)又(愚蠢)] = [(greedy) and (stupid)]

We don't say "this man is greedy but stupid" in English; We only say "this man is greedy and stupid"

~

(one positive, one negative)

[(迅速)但(不准确)] = [(fast) but (inaccurate)]

We don't say "his punch is fast and inaccurate" in English. For the same reason, we don't say "他的拳头又快速又不准确" in Chinese

[(贪心)但(守法)]= [(greedy) but (law abiding)]

We don't say "he is greedy and law abiding" in English. For the same reason, we don't say "他又贪心又守法" in Chinese

Answer (score 1):

@songyuanyao's comment is spot on.

The point is that the adjectives should be ***relevant***. The examples you made up sounds awkward ***not*** because of mixture of negative and positive adjectives.

E. g.  in 又爱又恨，爱 and 恨 are relevant(they are exactly opposite to each other).

Of course, by saying *relevant*, all negatives or positives can be ***a way of being relevant***.  As shown in this example you quoted:

> 他有点成问题，又懒、又邋遢、又不讲卫生。

where 懒、邋遢、不讲卫生 are consistent, which is kind of *being relevant*.

In 又高又瘦, 高 and 瘦 is relevant in the way they describe the shape of one's body.  You can also put 又高又胖.

Anyways, the whole point is to find a way of being relevant, any ways you can think of and can make sense.