# Can I say 又可爱又恐怖?

Tags: grammar, phrase

可爱 is positive whilst 恐怖 is negative.

For 又A又B , do A and B have to be both positive or both negative? Or can one be positive and the other negative?

I want to say ''these pictures are kinda cute and kinda horrific''.

这些图又可爱又恐怖

有问题吗 ？

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate: [In the grammar structure 又 \[adjective\] 又 \[adjective\], is there anything wrong with combining a negative adjective with a positive one?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/27748) (although I got a rather different answer).

Comment: @Becky李蓓 The adjectives should be "relevant".  That's why I put 又可爱又可怖 as an improvement because 可爱 and 可怖 are closer than 可爱 and 恐怖.

Comment: I remember It is used to describe the new web drama serie "The Hidden Corner"? Yes, you can describe it with these word, because this drama is sometimes cute(songs), and sometimes horror(events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be a problem. because we have this commonly said:

> 我对她又爱又恨。

> ……又可气又好笑。

And in your case, this might be an improvement:

> 这些图片又可爱又**可怖**。

Or

> 这些图片既可爱又可怖。

It's worth to note that the point is that the adjectives should be ***relevant***.  The comment suggests 又好气又好笑 is better than 又可气又好笑 because 好气 and 好笑 are more relevant than 可气 and 好笑.

Comment: 又可气又好笑...should be 又好氣又好笑。

Comment: @HungYuChang Yeah, that's an improvement.  But I think 又可气又好笑 is ok.

Comment: 可氣又好笑 sounds odd, I‘ve never use or heard  that before. 令人生氣又好笑, 好氣又好笑 are more fluent and common.(Taiwan)